# What is the Flow equivalent of React.PropTypes.node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

What is the Flow equivalent of `React.PropTypes.node` (i.e., anything that can be rendered by React, if there is one? Do I have to create it myself as a union type?

In other words, what would replace `???` here?

```
type Props = {
  children: ???,
}

const UselessComponent
  : (props: Props) => React$Element<*>
  = ({ children }) => (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )

UselessComponent.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like it is still an issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1355).

According to the discussion in that issue, what you should do until it is fixed:

```
type Props = {
  children?: React.Element<*>,
};
```

Answer (score 9):

For versions of flow >= 0.53, use the new type `React.Node` for props.children and anywhere you are expecting a renderable node.

> The definition of React.Node can be roughly approximated with a
>   React.ChildrenArray:
>
> ```
> type Node = React.ChildrenArray<void | null | boolean | string |
> number | React.Element<any>>;
> ```

There was a major rework of the react types in flow 0.53.    Summary of the changes and instructions on how to migrate are in the [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.53.0). 
 The [flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/) explain how to use in detail.

For example:

```
import type { Node } from 'react';

type Props = {
  input?: Node,
}
```